# O does not fit standalone class

Tags: margins, standalone

[image]

Why are the top and bottom of the O cut off when I use the standalone class without any larger symbols?

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\begin{document}%
O%
\end{document}%
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option `[border=<size>]` to change the margin.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
O
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aren't.  Without `12pt` and `\Huge` is also OK, but less visible.

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}%
\begin{document}%
\Huge

O%
\end{document}%

[image]

(Sorry that not as a comment, but i don't know, how to add a picture there).